# Filter multiples in a pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, filter

My data can be easily converted into a pandas dataframe that looks something like:

```
import pandas as pd
data={'a':["t", "g"]*9,'b' [1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6],'distance':[10, 15, 290, 300, 315, 320, 350, 360, 10, 25, 225, 240, 325, 335, 365, 205, 15, 35]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['a','b','distance'])
print df

    a  b  distance
0   t  1        10
1   g  2        15
2   t  3       290
3   g  4       300
4   t  5       315
5   g  6       320
6   t  1       350
7   g  2       360
8   t  3        10
9   g  4        25
10  t  5       225
11  g  6       240
12  t  1       325
13  g  2       335
14  t  3       365
15  g  4       205
16  t  5        15
17  g  6        35
```

I want to erase all the lines that have the same value in the "b" column but keep the one line with the smallest value in the "distance" column. In this case I would like to erase all the lines that have a "distance" greater than 200 so that, in this example, only the lines with the index 0,1,8,9,16,17 remain. In the end all the lines should have a different "b" value and the smallest "distance". It would look like:

```
    a  b  distance
0   t  1        10
1   g  2        15
2   t  3        10
3   g  4        25
4   t  5        15
5   g  6        35
```

How could I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`groupby` on `b` col and call `idxmin` on `distance` column to index the orig df:

```
In [114]:
df.loc[df.groupby('b')['distance'].idxmin()]

Out[114]:
    a  b  distance
0   t  1        10
1   g  2        15
8   t  3        10
9   g  4        25
16  t  5        15
17  g  6        35
```

Here you can see that `idxmin` returns the indices of the lowest values:

```
In [115]:
df.groupby('b')['distance'].idxmin()

Out[115]:
b
1     0
2     1
3     8
4     9
5    16
6    17
Name: distance, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That is a very smart solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 df.groupby('b')['a','b','distance'].min()


#      a  b  distance
#    b                
#    1  t  1        10
#    2  g  2        15
#    3  t  3        10
#    4  g  4        25
#    5  t  5        15
#    6  g  6        35


​
```